# How to change column data in Linux, that starts from a specific line

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to replace the content of my Column 1 with "chr" added into it. But I want this to be added from the 15th line onwards, otherwise it changes the header information.

I used this command:

`awk '{$1 = "chr"$1; print}' sample81a.vcf > sample81A.vcf`

but like I mentioned,` it is changing the header too.

How to ensure that the "chr" starts only from line 15 of column 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NR>=15` condition to start executing code inside `{...}` from line #15 onwards:

```
awk 'NR>=15 {$1 = "chr" $1} 1' sample81a.vcf > sample81A.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{count=0}{++count;if(count >= 15)$1="char"$1;print}' sample81a.vcf > sample81A.vcf
```